# How to run the same function on different schemas

Tags: postgresql, plpgsql

I have multiple schemas / user with the same structure but different data. There are some stored functions executed on these data, and so far, they are stored in each schema. I'd like to store these functions together in a new schema, which would make it easier, updating the code, ... as it would be centralized.

I thought, as the `search_path` is defined to be `"$user",public` it would reference to the user of the current session / connection, hence those also queries from different schemas would ultimately have the same search_path.

let's say I have a table `T1` for the users `u1, u2, u3` and a function which uses this table `F1`.

Originally, `F1` would be in copied into the schemas `u1, u2, u3` and running `select * from F1()` would work for each user. However updating the function would become increasingly difficult with the number of users, so I want to have a new schema `functions` with only one `F1` function inside.

Now, running `select * from functions.F1()` returns an error, that `T1` couldn't be found. But the users `search_path`s contain still the same information. So why does the search_path change based on the function which is executing it, and how can I prevent it from happening?

There was a mail about this on postgres mailing list: http://postgresql.nabble.com/function-doesn-t-see-change-in-search-path-td4971325.html and the final workaround was my original situation. Maybe something change in the meanwhile?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, my thinking was correct. However when I created the new schema, by exporting the old function, `pg_dump` added `SECURITY DEFINER` at the definition of each function.

Changing this to `SECURITY INVOKER` gives the behavior as expected (by me)

from the [documentation](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/sql-createfunction.html):

> SECURITY INVOKER indicates that the function is to be executed with the privileges of the user that calls it. That is the default. SECURITY DEFINER specifies that the function is to be executed with the privileges of the user that created it.

Answer (score 0):

[Add a `table` parameter to F1.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10705616/table-name-as-a-postgresql-function-parameter) Then add `uf1`, `uf2`, and `uf3` to `u1`, `u2`, and `u3`. These functions will just call `F1` and pass in the correct table.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [plproxy](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/PL/Proxy). This is what Skype used to run queries over multiple database shards via a proxy database with wrapper functions.

You could also write a wrapper function which finds all of the functions in every schema and calls them.